# React show data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend

Today I made a useFetch hook to get all the data from a certain category. As you can see on the image it's possible to see all the data in JSON format. Also you can see that it is in an array of objects. I was wondering how I can show this data in normal format like  on the page. Most of the time I'm getting the error of data.name NULL. But as you can see the data is fetched correctly in JSON format on the image. I just don't understand how to show all this data normally. Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVO6H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoYEz.png)

```
import React from "react";
import "../Style/menu.css";
import { useParams, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../ApiService/useFetch";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

const Product = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data, error, isPending } = useFetch("http://localhost:8080/products/category/" + id);

        return (
            <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
        )
}

export default Product;
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsPending] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError ] = useState(null);


useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url) //custom url so you can reuse it
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.ok) {
                throw Error('could not fetch data');
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data =>  {
            setData(data);
            setIsPending(false)
            setError(null)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setError(null)
            setIsPending(false)
        })
    }, [url]);

    return {data, isLoading, error} //use properties with custom hook
}

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` just before your `return` in `useFetch` and see what it shows on the console

Comment: It gives me an array of all the objects i need to display! Also i added the pictures

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to render it in the HTML? There's [docs with examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)  for that.

Comment: What is the output if you don't pass `data` to `JSON.stringify` ? Probably you'll be getting regular array so can `map` over that array and render in whatever way you want.

Comment: this : Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, allergies, price}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: And when i do data.name to get the name from the products per category it says: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Comment: @SemdeWilde rather accessing `data.name` try `data[0].name`.

Comment: Then it says: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Comment: Your component is being rendered before you have data. It gets re-rendered when you do have data. You need to check your loading prop or data as appropriate before trying to read from it.

Comment: agree with @Nikki9696 . Well, in this case you can conditionally render your data.

Comment: Do you guys have a piece of code so i can try this? Because i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful for you

```
...

const Product = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data, error, isPending } = useFetch("http://localhost:8080/products/category/" + id);

        return (
            { data && data.length &&
                data.map((row) =>{
                  <p>row.name</p>
                })
            }
        )
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

your useFetch is async, as I can see isPending variable, why don't you use this ?

```
const { id } = useParams();
const { data, error, isPending } = useFetch("http://localhost:8080/products/category/" + id);


    return (
        <p>{isPending ? null : JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    )
```